# Jquery UI - header with fixed position and content with scroll

Tags: css, jquery-ui, layout

In the layout of an aplication i am developing, the content is divided by tabs, im using Jquery UI. I want that the user can scroll through the content(vertical and horizontal scroll), but i also want that the header of the tab widget was always on a fixed position, but it seems that position:fixed; disallows the scroll and i only can see the content that fits into the screen.
Another feature is that the div i use to initialize the tab is also in a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by using `position: absolute` on the header element.

Then you can offset the contained elements using a top padding: `padding-top: 30px` (where 30px is the height of the header).

Note that `position: absolute` is relative to the closest parent that has its `position` attribute set to anything but `static`.